# Structuring a multi-dimensional object with varying data

Tags: javascript, object

I have three functions which create three objects, `firstPayment`, `interimPayment` and `finalPayment`

`firstPayment` will always have data. But `interimPayment` shouldn't always be used, same `finalPayment`.

The signifier that `interimPayment` or `finalPayment` isn't needed is based on another variable `numberOfPayments`.

If `numberOfPayments === 1` then only `firstPayment` will have data. If `numberOfPayments === 2` then both `firstPayment` and `finalPayment` are needed. And finally if `numberOfPayments > 2` then all three payment objects are needed.

I'm trying to work out how to add all these objects to another object `paymentSchedule` based on the `numberOfPayments` variable.

Here's my start on the code but I'm a bit lost!

```
  getPaymentSchedule(id) {
    const firstPayment = this.getFirstPayment(id);
    const numberOfPayments = this.getNumberOfPayments(id);

    if (numberOfPayments === 2) {
      const finalPayment = this.getFinalPayment(id);
    } else if (numberOfPayments > 2) {
      const interimPayments = this.getInterimPayments(id);
    }
  }
```

This is where I'm a bit stuck. I need to add the three objects `firstPayment`, `getInterimPayments` and `finalPayment` in that order, but obviously only if they have been set. I feel like I could do this some quicker way than lots and lots of if statements.

Example of `paymentSchedule` I am trying to achieve:

```
{
    firstPayment: {
        label: "foo",
        amount: 123
    },
    interimPayment: {
        label: "foo",
        amount: 123
    },
    finalPayment: {
        label: "foo",
        amount: 123
    },
}

or

{
    firstPayment: {
        label: "foo",
        amount: 123
    },
    finalPayment: {
        label: "foo",
        amount: 123
    },
}
```

Comment: please add the object as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz which object do you mean?

Comment: This is about design. It's difficult to say how the design should be without knowing how payment and schedule is used. Can you explain what you're trying to do? I assume you're using ES6 classes?

Comment: @Halcyon paymentSchedule has not yet been created. I am trying to create it in this function. The three objects mentioned are just `{ "label":"foo", "amount":123 }`

Comment: I understand that but what the schedule should look like is determined by how you use it. You can't just return an object with the 3 payment-keys, because they're optional based on the number of payments.

Comment: @Halcyon added example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but is this what you're looking for?

```
getPaymentSchedule(id) {
    const numberOfPayments = this.getNumberOfPayments(id);
    const schedule = {};
    schedule.firstPayment = this.getFirstPayment(id);

    if (numberOfPayments === 2) {
        schedule.finalPayment = this.getFinalPayment(id);
    } else if (numberOfPayments > 2) {
        schedule.interimPayments = this.getInterimPayments(id);
    }
    return schedule;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I just realised I need to swap the order around, as I need interimPayments to come before finalPayments, so perhaps this should be an array of objects?

Comment: You can't sort objects so if order is important then you need something else. I feel like I'm missing the opportunity for a design here. Why is order is important?

Comment: I need to then iterate through and output the data. But it must be first payment > interim payment > final payment. So it must be in order

Comment: I don't think I'm going to able to help you through StackOverflow. Is there someone nearby who can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with objects. The array reflects the order and the objects.

```
[
    {                              // exists always
        name: 'firstPayment',
        label: 'foo',
        amount: 123            
    },
    {                              // numberOfPayments > 2
        name: 'interimPayment',
        label: 'foo',
        amount: 123            
    },
    {                              // numberOfPayments > 1
        name: 'finalPayment',
        label: 'foo',
        amount: 123            
    }
]
```

To generate, you could use something like this

```
var schedule = [].concat(
        this.getFirstPayment(id)
        numberOfPayments > 2 ? this.getInterimPayments(id) : [],
        numberOfPayments > 1 ? this.getFinalPayment(id) : []
    );
```

This generates an array with the wanted payment date.